# Obtener un parámetro de la URL con Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Estoy teniendo un problema para poder obtener un parámetro de la url. Puedo obtener los parámetros de la siguiente manera, pero yo necesito que me lo devuelva como un objeto (porque luego debo hacer algo con uno de esos parámetros). Así funciona ok:

```
    const query = this.$window.location.search;
    console.log('query', query);
```

y para obtener uno de esos parámetros, estoy haciendo:

```
    const query = this.$window.location.search.slice(1);
    const parsed = this.qsp.toObject(query);
    const search = angular.copy(parsed);
    const outboundFlightAirlineCode = 
    search.outboundFlightAirlineCode.split(',')[0];
    const flightDatetime = search.flightDatetime.split(',')[0];

    this.search = search;
    this.flightDatetime = flightDatetime;       
    this.outboundFlightAirlineCode = outboundFlightAirlineCode;

    console.log('one',flightDatetime);
    console.log('two',outboundFlightAirlineCode);
```

y aquí me salta un error que es :

> Cannot read property 'toObject' of undefined

¿Qué puede estar fallando?

Comment: No me queda claro si estás trabajando con Angular o con AngularJS. Son dos frameworks que no tienen nada que ver, pero e ntu código no hace uso de ninguno de los dos... aunque ese `this.$window`me recuerda más a AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

Como dice [dddenis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2676/dddenis), ese es un método valido. Pero también existe el siguiente:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {

   this.urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);

   this.token = this.urlTree.queryParams['token'];
   this.typeGame = this.urlTree.queryParams['type'];
};
```

---

### Metodo 1

Con el método que te mostró dddenis, recibos los parámetros que vienen por ruteo interno de Angular de la siguiente forma:

```
{
    path: 'baseURL/:id/:name',
    component: yourComponent
  }
```

Y deberias leer el "ID" y el "NAME" de la siguiente forma:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  const id: any = params['id'] || null;
  const name: any = params['name'] || null;
  // Código...
});
```

### Metodo 2

En cambio si los parámetros llegan en tu URL de la siguiente forma, la cual suele suceder :

```
baseURL/filter?type=slot&username=fedem&agent=someagentname
```

Puedes tomar esos parámetros de la siguiente forma:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {

   this.urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);

   this.username = this.urlTree.queryParams['username'];
   this.type = this.urlTree.queryParams['type'];
   this.agent = this.urlTree.queryParams['agent'];

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener los parámetros de una URL con **Angular** debes de utilizar el servicio [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute):

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  const data: any = params['data'] || null;
  // Código...
});
```